# Passing arg between launches

Tags: roslaunch

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I have a master .launch file that runs another .launch.
My problem is when i do the example of the (http://wiki.ros.org/roslaunch/XML/arg), i get an error message `included file [/home/user/catkin_ws/src/] requires the 'test' arg to be set`.

```
<launch>
<group if="$(arg cam)">
    <include file="$(find openni_launch)/launch/openni.launch">
             <arg name="Kinect" value="1.5" />
    </include>
</group>
</launch>
```

And on the other file i have:

```
<launch>
<arg name="Kinect"/>
....
<param name="Test" value="$(arg Kinect)"/>
</launch>
```

Anyone can help me?

Thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/243131/passing-arg-between-launches/) by [joaoleao](https://answers.ros.org/users/27904/joaoleao/) on ROS Answers with karma: 13 on 2016-09-05

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I don't see anything in the sample you posted that would cause the error you describe.

That error usually indicates that your included launch file has an `<arg>` tag without a default value, and you aren't providing a value for that argument. I would check your included launch file for a line like: `<arg name="test">`.

If you can't find this on your own, please post a complete sample that reproduces the issue; maybe by removing the other parts of the launch file and checking that it still produces the same error.

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2016-09-05

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [joaoleao](https://answers.ros.org/users/27904/joaoleao/) on 2016-09-06**:
Thanks, problem solve.